# Did an anti-Trump protest hold up a "Rape Melania" sign?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

Maajid Nawaz [tweeted](https://twitter.com/MaajidNawaz/status/798034665877766144) that someone at an anti-Trump held up an "Rape Melania" sign (in reference to [Melania Trump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melania_Trump)):

> [image]
>
> [image]

But some commenters are saying it's photoshopped:

> [image]

Did a protester show this sign or was it doctored?

Comment: [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/2016/11/14/melania-sign-at-anti-trump-protest/) presents the evidence, but doesn't draw a conclusion.

Comment: Sure was picked up by many, many (over 100k) Twitter accounts.

Comment: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/11/15/how-one-deplorable-sign-at-an-anti-trump-protest-foreshadows-the-fight-over-fake-news/?tid=sm_fb

Comment: @Avery I'd say your link qualifies as an answer.

Comment: Some fairly specific allegations [here](https://www.buzzfeed.com/josephbernstein/inside-the-alt-rights-campaign-to-smear-trump-protesters-as?utm_term=.seWOxLpW5N#.xgKP5wY02r) as to the source of the sign. (BuzzFeed has not much credibility these days, neither does Gionet, but they describe how they allegedly verified source's claims. It is unverifiable by _us_, as we do not have access to the source. Also alluded to back in November by WaPo, [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/11/15/how-one-deplorable-sign-at-an-anti-trump-protest-foreshadows-the-fight-over-fake-news/).)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on the [link offered by Avery](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/11/15/how-one-deplorable-sign-at-an-anti-trump-protest-foreshadows-the-fight-over-fake-news/?tid=sm_fb) **the sign was in fact displayed at the protest**, and other protestors acted pretty quickly to get the sign taken down.

The article mentions that some people drew a conclusion that it was pretty likely that the person holding the sign and the person who took the photograph worked together, either to discredit the protest or just to troll, but there is no proof of either version presented.

Comment: There is now [evidence](https://www.buzzfeed.com/josephbernstein/inside-the-alt-rights-campaign-to-smear-trump-protesters-as) that the person holding the sign was likely far-right activist Jack Posobiec.